# how to find increment nearest(closest) text box value after button click in javascript

Tags: javascript, php

[This image  only one text box value increment in textbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYG2O.png)
i want to all textbox value increment by button.
all button

```js
var a = 1;
var val = '';

function add() {

  var c = 0;
  var textBox = document.getElementById("add1");
  c = textBox.value;
  textBox.value = ++c;
  a++;
  var val = $(this).closest("div.minicarts-details-quantity").find("input[name='add1']").val();
  //$(this).closest('li').prev().find('input.product-price').val();
  alert(val);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="minicarts-details-quantity">
  <input class="minicarts-quantity" id="add1" data-minicarts-idx="<%= i %>" name="quantity_<%= idx %>" type="text" pattern="[0-9]*" value="<%= items[i].get(" quantity ") %>" autocomplete="off" />
  <button type="button" class="minicarts-quantity" onclick="return add();">+</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @husen. Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please consider editing your answer to include the code correctly.

If you are using jQuery, check: https://api.jquery.com/siblings/

Comment: Can you please tell us what you are exactly trying, I mean more explanation would  be better...

Comment: Is this using some sort of JS framework? It doesn't look completely normal, especially the attribute values in your input field. You should include the framework in your question as a tag if you're using one. I.e. Vue, angular, react etc. This doesn't look normal to me at all.

Comment: @Martin attributes looks like php variables (also tagged as php)

Comment: @Dementic I don't see any PHP tags in the code. `<%=` and `%>` seems to be something called EJS (Embedded JS). So far I see jQuery, JavaScript, EJS and HTML.